# Factor $x^3 + 6 y x^2 + 12 x y^2 + 8y^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Polynomial: $x^3 + 6yx^2 + 12xy^2 + 8y^3$

The simplest factorization is $(x+2y)^3$.  How does one factor it into this form?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! See this for how to format your answers in MathJax:https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
In your case, wrapping your math in "$" fixes everything.

Comment: Use Binomial Theorem on $8y^3 = (2y)^3$.

Comment: In this case, you can "guess" the factorization ; $x^3$ and $8y^3$ are cubes, so $(x+2y)^3$ might be the factorization.

Answer (score 3):

Alt. hint:   using the homogeneity of the expression, look for factors of $\,z^3 + 6z^2+12z+8\,$ where $\,z = x/y\,$. The [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) finds them fairly quickly.

Answer (score 2):

If you already know the answer to the "simplification", it's sometimes easier to start there and work your way back. Observe,
\begin{align}
  (x + 2y)^3 &= (x + 2y)(x + 2y)(x + 2y)\\
  &= (x^2 + 4xy + 4y^2)(x + 2y)\\
  &= x^3 + 2x^2 y + 4x^2 y + 8x y^2 + 4y^2 x + 8y^3\\
  &= x^3 + 6x^2 y + 12xy^2 + 8y^3
\end{align}
So expanding it to verify is tedious, but it's easy. Going backwards, however, is pretty challenging. It's always easy to expand just polynomials, but factoring will be an eternal struggle. In fact, this idea of a mathematical operation being easy to carry out one way, but hard to reverse is the basis of many security systems.. As you gain more experience, you'll know what to guess.

If you know the biomial theorem, you might see the expanded form and recognize the 3rd row of Pascal's triangle
\begin{matrix}
&&&&&1\\
&&&&1&&1\\
&&&1&&2&&1\\
&&1&&3&&3&&1\\
\end{matrix}
Except it's been multiplied by $2^0, 2^1, 2^2$, and $2^3$ to get $1, 6, 12, 8$ instead of $1, 3, 3, 1$. This might lead you to guess that the factored form of $x^3 + 6x^2y + 12xy^3 + 8y^3$ is $(x + 2y)^3$. Again, there's no "formula" that can really help you guess this apart from the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) and a whole lot of experience.

Comment: Why not use the binomial formula to expand $(x+2y)^3$?

Comment: Of course that works as well. I wanted to show that without knowing much at all, verifying the expansion of $(x + 2y)^3$ is an easy (albeit tedious) process. The binomial formula is definitely the more civilized way of showing that, and I made an attempt at demonstrating that in the second half of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a cubic and has leading term $x^3$, try the form $(x + a y)^3$, expand and solve for $a$ and find $a = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to simplify this, I'd start by trying the easier problem you get when you plug in $y=1$.  So I'd try to factor $x^3 +6x^2+12x+8$.  By the rational root theorem, any rational root has to divide $8$, so I try to divide the polynomial by $x-a$ where $a = \pm 1, \pm2, \pm4, \pm 8$.  I would discover that $x+2$ divides the polynomial and so it factors as $(x+2)(x^2+4x+4)$.  Then I could factor the last quadratic to get $(x+2)(x+2)(x+2)$.   Then it would be obvious that I just need to stick the $y$ back in. $(x+2y)^3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}x^3 +6yx^2 +12xy^2 +8y^3 &=x^3 + 3x^2\cdot2y + 3x\cdot4y^2 +8y^3\\ &=x^3 + 3x^2(2y) + 3x(2y)^2 +(2y)^3\\ &=(x+2y)^3.\end{align}$$